# UITextField in UITableViewCell and validation in modal view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield

I am using the approach described in [this stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375442/accessing-uitextfield-in-a-custom-uitableviewcell) to retrieve values from a textfield. My problem is that the tableview is presented modally and I have a `save` button that validates the input and stores it.

The problem is that the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method is **not** called when the user clicks an `UIBarButtonItem` (= the save button, which closes the modal view).

In this event (when the user wants to save the input) I would like to validate it. But the values are stored in properties in the `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Due to the fact that this method is not called, I cannot validate the input values correctly.

Does anyone have a hint or solution on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here we go:

Thanks to @Lefteris and his idea with storing the current index. Due to the fact that I cannot  store the index into the `tag` attribute I decided to store the active `indexPath` and additionally the active `textField`. (I know, a reference to the `UITextField` would have been enough but I needed it for other stuff)

First I have added these two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *activeIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *activeTextField;
```

Then I implemented `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:` of `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)[self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)[[textField superview] superview]];

    self.activeTextField = textField;
    self.activeIndexPath = indexPath;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    NSString *input = textField.text;    

    //assuming values from input textfield into corresponding properties
    [self assumeInput:input withIndexPath:self.activeIndexPath];

    self.activeTextField = nil;
    self.activeTextField = nil;
}
```

In `textFieldDidEndEditing:` I am storing the values into my properties (such as `self.firstName`, `self.lastName`, and so on...) by using the method `[self assumeInput:input withIndexPath:self.activeIndexPath];`.

In my `saveAction`-Method I am storing the value from the currently active `TextField`.

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender 
{    
    //assuming input from active field (didEndEditing _not_ called right now!)
    [self assumeInput:self.activeTextField.text withIndexPath:self.activeIndexPath];

    //test output
    NSLog(@"firstName: %@", self.firstName);
    NSLog(@"lastName: %@", self.lastName);
    NSLog(@"email: %@", self.email);
    ...
}
```

... and that's it!

Hope it helps! Thanks to @Lefteris for his input.

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You should assign unique tag numbers to your text fields, then keep track on which is currently active (i.e. use a int iVar to store the active text fields tag value) in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate and when the user clicks the save, you should get the last textfield by it's tag value and then it's text value so you can validate it.

Comment: I can't use the `tag` attribute. I'm currently using it to retrieve the textfield from the cell (`[cell viewForTag:...]`). Any other suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Great idea with storing the index but I have improved it a little bit.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't access the textview by the tag, even if it's in a cell. Just use unique tag numbers, and once you get a reference to the cell, do a UITextView *myTextView = (UITextView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:XXX];

Comment: Yep, this works (basically the same how I have done and described in my post below). I thought, how you have described in your post above, that I have to assign a unique tag number over all cells. The tag is unique **inside** a cell but not alongside all rows.