# How to handle Table View cell with textfield

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uitextfield, uitableviewrowaction

My tableview cell contain one label and one textfield, I am reusing my cell and it is working. but when I enter text in first textfield and hit return I want to go to next textfield, how can I handle that?

[image]

Comment: make your next textfield as first responder after return key press of first textfield

Comment: ref this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375442/accessing-uitextfield-in-a-custom-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

1. Created a delegate protocol with these methods:

   ```
   - (void)textFieldInCellDidReturn:(UITableViewCell*)cell;
   - (void)textFieldInCellDidBeginEditing:(UITableViewCell*)cell;
   - (void)textFieldInCellDidEndEditing:(UITableViewCell*)cell;
   ```
2. In the cell:

   ```
   -(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
   {
       return [self.inputTextField becomeFirstResponder];
   }

   -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
       if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldInCellDidBeginEditing:)])
       {
           [self.delegate textFieldInCellDidBeginEditing:self];
       }
   }
   -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
       if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldInCellDidEndEditing:)])
       {
           [self.delegate textFieldInCellDidEndEditing:self];
       }
   }
   -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
   {
       if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldInCellDidReturn:)])
       {
           [self.delegate textFieldInCellDidReturn:self];
       }
       return NO;
   }
   ```
3. In the view controller and table view delegate, declare the iVar `NSIndexPath* indexPathOfFirstResponder` and adopt the delegate

   ```
   - (void)textFieldInCellDidBeginEditing:(UITableViewCell *)cell
   {
       indexPathOfFirstResponder = [self.theTable indexPathForCell:cell];
   }

   -(void)textFieldInCellDidReturn:(UITableViewCell *)cell
   {
       NSIndexPath* indexPathForCell = [self.theTable indexPathForCell:cell];
       if(indexPathForCell.row < [self.theTable numberOfRowsInSection:indexPathForCell.section]-1)
       {
           NSIndexPath* nextIndexPathInSection = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathForCell.row+1 inSection:indexPathForCell.section];
           UITableViewCell* nextCellInSection = [self.theTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPathInSection];
           if (nextCellInSection)
           {
               [nextCellInSection becomeFirstResponder];
           }
           else
           {
               indexPathOfFirstResponder = nextIndexPathInSection;
               [self.theTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPathInSection atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle) animated:YES];
           }
       }
       else
       {
           [self.theTable endEditing:YES];
       }
   }

   -(void)textFieldInCellDidEndEditing:(UITableViewCell *)cell
   {
       indexPathOfFirstResponder = nil;
   }

   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       if ([indexPath isEqual:indexPathOfFirstResponder])
       {
           [cell becomeFirstResponder];
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Set sequential tag for the textField e.g. 0,1,2.....
Import textField delegate method textFieldDidEndEditing. Whenever return key is pressed, this method gets called.

Use something like this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   if(textField.tag == currentTextFieldTag+1){
    [textField becomesFirstResponder];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your cell for row function use this code

```
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Now implement a `UITextFieldDelegate` Method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag+1 inSection:YOUR_SECTION];

UITableViewCell* cell = [yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.textField becomesFirstResponder]; 


 // if you need  [yourTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
     }
```

I hope this will help.Thankyou